# Prove that if $x+5$ is odd, then $x^2$ is even.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've been working on this for about an hour and cannot figure it out.

**Problem:** Prove that if $x+5$ is odd, then $x^2$ is even.

I've tried using induction, contrapositive, and contradiction methods. I cannot assume things like $1+\operatorname{even}= \operatorname{odd}$, only that $2k+1$ is odd and $2k$ is even where $k$ = integer.

Comment: First try to prove that x is even.

Comment: When $x+5$ is odd, then $x$ is even and therefore $x^2$ is even.

Comment: No one has answered my question. Is anyone familiar with logic and proofs? I don't need intuitive answers.

Comment: I added an answer, but others were faster. However, you could easily take those "intuitive answers" and make it rigorous. Take it as an extra exercise to prove that $1 + \text{even} = \text{odd}$ and $1 + \text{odd} = \text{even}$. The same can be done for $\text{odd} + \text{odd} = \text{even}$, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $x+5$ is odd, then by defintion, $\exists k\in \mathbb{Z}: x+5=2k+1.$

$$x+5 = 2k+1 \implies x=2k+1-5=2k-4$$
$$x=2k-4 = 2(k-2)$$
$$\implies x^2=4(k-2)^2=2(2(k-2)^2)$$
$$p=2(k-2)^2 \in \mathbb{Z} \implies x^2=2p$$
Thus, $x^2$ is even.

Comment: @user2665637 This is the accepted answer, but I'd say you better also use beedge89's answer's second line "Even numbers squared are even". If you are allowed to use the unique prime factorization of natural numbers, you can then skip on the explicit squaring of $x$ above.

Answer (score 6):

$x+5$ odd implies $x$ is even (odd minus odd) is even.

Even numbers squared are even.

Answer (score 1):

since " $x+5$ is odd" so "$x$ is even". therefore "$x^2$ is even":
for the last part note that if "$x$ is even" then we can write $x$ as: $x=2k$. so $x^2=4k^2=2\times 2k^2$, which is even.

Answer (score 0):

To prove $x^2$ is even, you must first prove that $x$ is even.

You must always remember the following rules:
$$odd + odd = even$$
$$odd + even = odd$$
$$even + even = even$$
Given $x+5$ is odd. Since odd + odd can never be odd, $x$ should be even .

*EDIT*

Continuing from where you left.

Case 1: Let $x$ be even.$$x=2k$$
$$x+5 = 2k+5 = even + odd = odd$$

Case 2: Let $x$ be odd.$$x=2k+1$$
$$x+5 = 2k+1+5 = 2k+6 = 2(k+3) = even$$

Hence $x$ should be even which implies $x^2$ should be even.

Comment: Can you recreate that with only, even = 2k and odd = 2k+1 where k are integers.

Comment: @user2665637 Is this what you wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

If $x+5$ is odd, then $x+4$ is even, so $x$ is even.

And if $x$ is even, then $x \cdot x = x^2$ must be even, too.

This follows from these statements:

- If $n$ is odd, then $n+1$ is even
- If $n$ is even, then $n+c$ is even, where $c$ is also even.
- An even number multiplied by another even number gives an even number.

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer:

$$x+5=2k+1$$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $$x=2k-4=2(k-2)$$ where we find $$x^2=(2(k-2))^2=4(k-2)^2=2(2(k-2)^2)=2c$$ where $c\in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence $x^2$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x+5$ be odd. Then there exists an integer $k$ such that $2k+1 = x+5$, hence $2k = x + 4$, so $x+4$ is even. It follows that $x = 2k-4 = 2(k-2)$. Since $k-2$ is an integer it follows that $x$ is even. Now let $x = 2c$ for an integer $c$, then $x^2 = (2c)^2 = 4c^2 = 2(2c^2)$ is even since $2c^2$ is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{aligned}x+5&=2k+1,k\in\Bbb{Z}\\
x&=2k-4,k\in\Bbb{Z}\end{aligned}$$Since $2k-4$ is even($4$ is even and even $-$ even $=$ even), $x$ is also even, implying that $x^2$ is also even.